# python-shout *** buffer overflow detected ***: terminated

Tags: python, buffer-overflow, icecast

script:

```py
import shout


s = shout.Shout()
print("Using libshout version %s" % shout.version())

s.audio_info = {shout.SHOUT_AI_BITRATE:'128', shout.SHOUT_AI_SAMPLERATE:'44800', shout.SHOUT_AI_CHANNELS:'2'}
s.name = 'Test radio connection'
s.url = 'http://localhost:8000/test.ogg'
s.mount = 'test.ogg'
s.port = 8000
s.user = 'username'
s.password = 'password'
s.genre = 'Other'
s.description = 'Test description'
s.host = 'localhost'
s.format = 'ogg'
s.open()
s.get_connected()
```

Output:

```py
Using libshout version 2.4.6
*** buffer overflow detected ***: terminated
```

OS: Windows 11
Msys2 Mingw64

The error is happens when `s.open()` is run.

Comment: What does this have to do with mys2??  Shouldn't it be tagged with Shout?

Comment: Sure tags changed.